# How to round all numeric values in text selection with other characters before or after them

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I want to round numbers embedded in text in a selection in Word. Unlike many solutions for rounding on the net, the values are not isolated in table cells etc. but may be in the text and have additional characters around them.
Examples: 0.0044***, (0.0040–0.0047) +/-0.0012.

I adapted the following code from [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233466/round-numbers-in-ms-word) which was designed to round to whole numbers:

```vb
Sub RoundNumbers()
Dim OrigRng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim FindPattern As String
Dim FoundVal As String
Dim decplace as Integer
Set OrigRng = Selection.Range
Set WorkRng = Selection.Range
FindPattern = "([0-9]){1,}.[0-9]{1,}"
decplace = 3
Do
    With WorkRng
        .SetRange OrigRng.Start, OrigRng.End ' using "set WorkRng = OrigRng" would cause them to point to the same object (OrigRng is also changed when WorkRng is changed)
        If .Find.Execute(findtext:=FindPattern, Forward:=True, _
          MatchWildcards:=True) Then
            .Expand wdWord ' I couldn't find a reliable way for greedy matching with Word regex, so I expand found range to word
            .Text = FormatNumber(Round(CDbl(.Text) + 0.000001, decplace), decplace, vbTrue)
        End If
    End With
Loop While WorkRng.Find.Found
End Sub
```

I thought I could extend the Round function to round to a specified number of decimals, e.g. `.Text = round(CDbl(.Text) + 0.000001, 3)`.

The problem with this is that the macro continues to find the first value in the selection and doesn't move to subsequent numbers. Presumably this is because, unlike the whole numbers, the rounded values still match the regex.

A solution suggested was to replace the count of digits post decimal from one or more {1,} with a fixed value e.g., {4}. This works if all the values to be rounded have the same format but doesn't have the flexibility I need.

So how can I get it to move to the next value? Alternatively, does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add some sample text plus the expected output - that would help to test the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, to process a whole document:

```
Sub DemoA()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<[0-9]@.[0-9]@>"
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    .Text = Format(.Text, "0.000")
   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

or to process just a selected range:

```
Sub DemoB()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
With Selection
  Set Rng = .Range
  .Collapse wdCollapseStart
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "<[0-9]@.[0-9]@>"
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute = True
    If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
    .Text = Format(.Text, "0.000")
   .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks also. Unlike @Timothy's code, your DemoB respects selections in text but it tables it appears to expand the select to include cells in the same group of rows or columns as the selection. Perhaps this is a Word thing.  Similarly, when a single value alone is selected, nothing happens.  Not a big deal but if you have any insights I'd be grateful.

Comment: Unless you use the column select tool in tables, anything you select that spans multiple rows includes from the start of the selection to the end of that row, plus the whole of any intervening rows, then from the start of the last row to the end of the selection. Code revised to ensure single number selections are processed correctly.

Comment: Your refinement works perfectly and thanks to the explanation and that of @Timothy I can see the limitations involved.  Playing around I see there is a .SelectColumn statement that might be able to be used in a macro for columns alone but as is the macro does exactly what I need.  Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you have is that you are not changing the range to reflect the text left to search.  You seem to be resetting to the start of the range each time.

The following code may help

```
Option Explicit


Public Sub RoundNumbers(ByVal ipRange As wordRange)
    
    Dim myRange As Word.Range
    If ipRange Is Nothing Then
        
        Set myRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
        
    Else
    
        Set myRange = ipRange.Duplicate
        
    End If
    
    Dim myPreservedRangeEnd As Long
    myPreservedRangeEnd = myRange.End
    
    Dim myFindPattern As String
    myFindPattern = "[0-9]{1,}.[0-9]{1,}"
    
    Dim myDecplace As Long
    myDecplace = 3
    
    Do
    
        Set myRange = FindWildCardPattern(myRange, myFindPattern)
        If myRange Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    
        myRange.Text = FormatNumber(Round(CDbl(myRange.Text) + 0.000001, myDecplace), myDecplace, vbTrue)
        ' At this point myRange is the newly inserted text so to search
        ' the remainder of the text in the selection we need to move
        ' the start to after the current range and replace the end of the
        ' current range with the preserved end of the selection range
        myRange.Start = myRange.End + 1
        myRange.End = myPreservedRangeEnd
        
    Loop
        
End Sub



Public Function FindWildCardPattern(ByVal ipRange As Range, ipFindPattern As String) As Range

    If ipRange Is Nothing Then

        Set ipRange = ActiveDocument.StoryRanges(wdMainTextStory)
        
    End If
    
    With ipRange
    
        With .Find
        
            .Text = ipFindPattern
            .Forward = True
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
            
        End With
            
        If .Find.Found Then
        
            Set FindWildCardPattern = .Duplicate
            
        Else
        
            Set FindWildCardPattern = Nothing
            
        End If
        
    End With
        
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The essential problem in your code is that you have the loop in the wrong place, and  you set `WordRng` back to the beginning with each loop. Absent any example text I used the text in your question to test. The following should work:

```
Sub RoundNumbers()
    Dim WorkRng As Range: Set WorkRng = Selection.Range
    Dim FindPattern As String: FindPattern = "([0-9]){1,}.[0-9]{1,}"
    Dim FoundVal As String
    Dim decplace As Integer
  
    decplace = 3
    With WorkRng
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = FindPattern
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            .Text = FormatNumber(Round(CDbl(.Text) + 0.000001, decplace), decplace, vbTrue)
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It shows the perils of niavely adapting the work of others.  Your code works well for me but there are two issues I haven't been able to resolve. First, the macro doesn't seem to respect any selection of text to be changed.  It changes all values from the beginning of the selection to the end of the document. This isn't a big deal but I'd like to understand how the code works and see why it would do this.  Also if you select just a number  e.g., 0.1234  and run the macro, nothing happens even though it would be a candidate for rounding.

Comment: @Andrew - Both issues are limitations of `Find`. The first can be overcome by using `.InRange()`, as macropod has done. The second occurs if the text to find begins at the very first character of the range. If you look at the Advanced Find dialog you will see that the command being executed is actually Find Next.